# NServiceBus ServiceInsight Bug/Issue

Tags: nservicebus, serviceinsight

I'm able to reproduce this, does anyone have workaround for this?

ServiceInsight, ServicePulse and ServiceControl are set up. I'm trying to send a message to an endpoint which is not started and does not have the queue configured. So I'm able to see the failed message in both ServicePulse and ServiceInsight.

Now I have created the queue and retry the failed message from ServicePulse, the message goes through successfully and ServicePulse is fine. Now ServiceInsight is throwing the following error for that particular endpoint. Only workaround for me now to get ServiceInsight working is to delete all the documents from RavenDB.

---

```
[General Info]
--------------------------
Application: 
Version:     1.0.0-beta5 Branch:'release-1.0.0' Sha:'cd08364c1fa2254cdf663feb7dd7d43cef5bd1d3'


[Technical Details]
--------------------------
Top-level Exception
Type:        System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Message:     Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: Status 0 is not implemented
Source:      Particular.ServiceInsight
Stack Trace: at NServiceBus.Profiler.Desktop.MessageList.MessageErrorInfo.GetImage() in y:\BuildAgent\work\2be762a799648224\src\ServiceInsight.Desktop\MessageList\MessageErrorInfo.cs:line 49
   at NServiceBus.Profiler.Desktop.MessageList.MessageErrorInfo..ctor(MessageStatus status) in y:\BuildAgent\work\2be762a799648224\src\ServiceInsight.Desktop\MessageList\MessageErrorInfo.cs:line 23
   at NServiceBus.Profiler.Desktop.MessageList.MessageListViewModel.GetMessageErrorInfo(StoredMessage msg) in y:\BuildAgent\work\2be762a799648224\src\ServiceInsight.Desktop\MessageList\MessageListViewModel.cs:line 228
   at NServiceBus.Profiler.Desktop.MessageList.MessageListView.OnRequestAdvancedMessageData(Object sender, GridColumnDataEventArgs e) in y:\BuildAgent\work\2be762a799648224\src\ServiceInsight.Desktop\MessageList\MessageListView.xaml.cs:line 42
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridControl.RaiseCustomUnboundColumnDataCore(GridColumnDataEventArgs e)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridControl.RaiseCustomUnboundColumnData(GridColumnDataEventArgs e)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridControl.DevExpress.Xpf.Data.IDataProviderEvents.GetUnboundData(Int32 listSourceRowIndex, String fieldName, Object value)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Data.GridDataProvider.DevExpress.Data.IDataControllerData.GetUnboundData(Int32 listSourceRow, DataColumnInfo column, Object value)
   at DevExpress.Data.Access.UnboundPropertyDescriptor.GetValueFromRowNumber(Int32 rowNumber)
   at DevExpress.Data.Access.UnboundPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object component)
   at DevExpress.Data.Helpers.BaseListDataControllerHelper.GetRowValue(Int32 listSourceRow, Int32 column, OperationCompleted completed)
   at DevExpress.Data.DataController.GetRowValue(Int32 controllerRow, Int32 column, OperationCompleted completed)
   at DevExpress.Data.BaseListSourceDataController.GetRowValue(Int32 controllerRow, Int32 column, OperationCompleted completed)
   at DevExpress.Data.DataController.GetRowValue(Int32 controllerRow, DataColumnInfo column, OperationCompleted completed)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Data.GridDataProvider.GetRowValue(Int32 rowHandle, DataColumnInfo info)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Data.GridDataProvider.GetRowValue(Int32 rowHandle, String fieldName)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.Native.VisualDataTreeBuilder.GetCellValue(GridCellData cellData)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridCellData.GetValue()
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridCellData.UpdateValue()
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridDataBase.OnDataChanged()
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridDataBase.<.cctor>b__0(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.Native.VisualDataTreeBuilder.UpdateCellData(RowData rowData, GridCellData cellData, ColumnBase column)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowData.UpdateCellData(ColumnBase column, GridColumnData cellData)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowData.<UpdateDataCore>b__d(ColumnBase col, GridColumnData cellData)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowData.IterateNotNullDataCore[TData](Dictionary`2 cache, Action`2 updateMethod)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowData.<>c__DisplayClass7.<IterateNotNullData>b__6()
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Locker.DoLockedAction(Action action)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowData.IterateNotNullData(Action`2 updateMethod)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowData.UpdateDataCore(ColumnBase column, Int32 listSourceRowIndex)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowData.UpdateData()
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowData.RefreshData()
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowData.AssignFrom(RowsContainer parentRowsContainer, NodeContainer parentNodeContainer, RowNode rowNode, Boolean forceUpdate)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowData.RowDataReusingStrategy.AssignFrom(RowsContainer parentRowsContainer, NodeContainer parentNodeContainer, RowNode rowNode, Boolean forceUpdate)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowDataBase.AssignVirtualizedRowData(RowsContainer parentRowsContainer, NodeContainer parentNodeContainer, RowNode node, Boolean forceUpdate)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowsContainerSyncronizerBase.AssignRowDataFromNodeContainer(NodeContainer nodeContainer, RowDataBase rowData, Int32 nodeIndex)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowsContainerSyncronizerBase.Syncronize(NodeContainer nodeContainer)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.Native.VisualDataTreeBuilder.Synchronize(RowsContainer dataContainer, NodeContainer nodeContainer)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowsContainer.Synchronize(NodeContainer nodeContainer)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.DetailRowsContainer.Synchronize(NodeContainer nodeContainer)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.Native.DataTreeBuilder.SynchronizeMasterNode()
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.MasterNodeContainer.OnItemsGenerated()
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.NodeContainer.GenerateItems(Int32 count)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.MasterNodeContainer.GenerateItems(Int32 count)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.DataPresenterBase.GenerateItems(Int32 count, Double availableHeight)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.DataPresenter.GenerateItems(Int32 count, Double availableHeight)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.DataPresenterBase.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)


[Assemblies]
--------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Autofac, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da
Caliburn.Core, Version=2.0.0.61292, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8e5891231f2ed21f
Caliburn.PresentationFramework, Version=2.0.0.61292, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8e5891231f2ed21f
Castle.Core, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc
DevExpress.Data.v13.1, Version=13.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v13.1, Version=13.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.Xpf.Docking.v13.1, Version=13.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v13.1, Version=13.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v13.1.Core, Version=13.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.Xpf.Layout.v13.1.Core, Version=13.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.v13.1, Version=13.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.Xpf.Mvvm.v13.1, Version=13.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.Xpf.PropertyGrid.v13.1, Version=13.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.Office2013.v13.1, Version=13.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a621a9e7e5c32e69
DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
ExceptionHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
ExceptionHandler.Wpf, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a
Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Mindscape.WpfDiagramming.FlowDiagrams, Version=3.0.1315.22118, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2e9c4ef235fd77f
Mindscape.WpfDiagramming.Foundation, Version=3.0.1315.22118, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2e9c4ef235fd77f
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
Particular.ServiceInsight, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
PresentationFramework.Aero, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
PresentationFramework-SystemCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
PresentationFramework-SystemData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
PresentationFramework-SystemXml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
RestSharp, Version=104.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Rhino.Licensing, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0b3305902db7183f
System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Dynamic, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Messaging, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
UIAutomationProvider, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
UIAutomationTypes, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35


[System]
--------------------------
Operating System
  Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
     CodeSet = 1252
     CSDVersion = Service Pack 1
     CurrentTimeZone = -300
     FreePhysicalMemory = 2052724
     OSArchitecture = 64-bit
     OSLanguage = 1033
     ServicePackMajorVersion = 1
     ServicePackMinorVersion = 0
     Version = 6.1.7601
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading ServiceInsight to the latest version resolved this issue. Sorry for bothering.